# How can I use PHP in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have to show the contact num from database when user click on the button.. 
but when I use php in javaScript it doesn't work for me...
here is HTML

```
<button name="showNo" id="phone1" onclick="myFunction()"><span>Show Phone No</span></button>
```

```
<p id="show">******</p>
```

here the JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    var hsh = document.getElementById("show");
    if ( hsh.value === "******" )
        hsh.value = "<?php echo $contact; ?>";
    else
        hsh.value = "Open Curtain";
}
</script>
```

is there any other method to do this,,?

Comment: What does the *rendered* Javascript look like? What do you mean, "doesn't work"? What's the error message?

Comment: There is no error shown.. But it do nothing when I click on the button..

Comment: @catcon - How would removing the quotes change anything? If `$contact` is a string, the quotes are required.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, `p` tag does not have value so you need to use innerHTML to get data from it and set it

```
var hsh = document.getElementById("show").innerHTML;
if(hsh === "******"){
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "<?php echo $contact; ?>";
}else{
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "<?php echo 'Open Curtain'; ?>";
}
```